# discord.py forms DM Feedback

Tags: discord.py

I wrote a code with discord.py forms. The code is for application on a server. A channel is currently broadcasting whether one has been accepted or rejected. but that should be sent as DM. How does it work? Here is the code:

```
 accepted = await confirm.start()
 partners = bot.get_channel(849693369385877504)
 em = discord.Embed(title=results.username, description="Deine Bewerbung wurde angenommen!", color=0x2F3136)
 em.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
 em.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
 await partners.send(embed=em)
 declined =  await confirm.start()
 partners = bot.get_channel(849693369385877504)
 em = discord.Embed(title=results.username, description="Deine Bewerbung wurde abgelehnt.", color=0x2F3136)
 em.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
 em.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
 await partners.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to a user, in your case `ctx.author`, use `await ctx.author.send(embed=em)` instead of `await partners.send(embed=em)`.

**References and useful links to the documentation of `discord.py`:**

- [member.send()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.send) or [user.send()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.send)
- [ctx.author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Context.author)